# Creating a switch-statement

Tags: r, switch-statement

Recently, I needed to convert a series of dates from the form `"July 25, 2010"` to the standard R format `"2010-07-25"`:

```
> head(old.data$dateoccurred)`
[1] "April 9, 2004"     "September 1, 2004" "February 7, 2005
```

To solve this, I would like to make a 12-case switch-statement that returns the the numeric representation of a month; however, R does not support a native switch (at least, I could not find one).

As such, what is the most R-like way to create a switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DrewConway nicely answers the switch question.  The underlying date question has functions specifically for it. strptime() will convert the string to a standard time object which you can format as anything you like.

```
strptime("September 1, 2004", "%B %d, %Y")

[1] "2004-09-01"
```

(of course the string constant in the expression above can be replaced with your vector of strings)

Comment: Thanks, John.  I did not know of that function.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by the use of `dict` in Python to [replicate switch behavior](http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/7/switch/).  Rather than have a native switch, create a `list` that is indexed by the month names with values for the numeric equivalent:

```
months<-list("January"="01","February"="02","March"="03","April"="04","May"="05","June"="06","July"="07","August"="08","September"="09","October"="10","November"="11","December"="12")
```

With this list, it is straightforward to use `sapply` to create the conversion:

```
new.dates<-sapply(as.character(old.data$dateoccurred),function(x) paste(strsplit(x," ")[[1]][3],month.convert(strsplit(x," ")[[1]][1]),sub(",","",strsplit(x," ")[[1]][2]),sep="-"))
```

Now we have the data formatted the way I wanted.

```
head(new.data$dateoccurred)
[1] 2004-04-09 2004-09-01 2005-02-07 2005-02-19 2005-02-22 2005-03-11
264 Levels: 2004-04-09 2004-09-01 2005-02-07 2005-02-19 2005-02-22 2005-03-11 2005-03-15 2005-03-19 2005-05-13 2005-06-28 2005-06-29 2005-07-05 ... 2009-12-22
```

Comment: Nice trick, Drew, but the R-ish way to do this is indeed in John's answer.  Parse the date strings into `Date()` types (that you can validate, compute on, do `difftime()` with etc pp) and then format back to whichever other textual representation you prefer.